# Update grouped records with sequence in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following structure of data in Oracle table

```
COL1    COL2    COL2   GRP_ID
A       A       B      1
A       A       B      1
A       A       C      2
A       A       B      1
A       D       E      3
A       D       E      3
F       G       H      4
F       G       H      4
```

Basically each unique combination of col1, col2 and col3 has different value in GRP_ID column.

I need to replace value in GRP_ID column with database sequence value such that (assuming next value of sequence is 235678):

```
COL1    COL2    COL2   GRP_ID
A       A       B      235678
A       A       B      235678
A       A       C      235679
A       A       B      235678
A       D       E      235680
A       D       E      235680
F       G       H      235681
F       G       H      235681
```

There are millions of records in the table so I do not want to go through a loop. Reason to use database sequence is that the number provided by sequence will be exposed to customer and therefore it should not repeat when next communication is sent to customer.

Is there a way to do this through SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you need to do it only once (an update). It's much faster just to write a pl/sql block and make this update then to find a throw away sql solutiion. Or you need to that regularly?

Comment: If you want to make us our life easier, what do you say if you make an example on sql fiddler so all we can start with it. I think i know how to do that query but don't have enough time to do it

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if is the fastest way but it works.

```
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT
      RETURN NUMBER IS
      v_nextval NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      v_nextval := NEW_SEQUENCE.nextval;

      RETURN(v_nextval);
   END;
/

UPDATE EXAMPLE
SET EXAMPLE.GroupID = 
  (  
   SELECT G.GroupID FROM 
   ( 
     SELECT B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3, MY_SCHEMA.NEXT() AS GroupID 
     FROM EXAMPLE B 
     GROUP BY B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3
   ) G 
   Where G.Column1 = EXAMPLE.Column1 AND G.Column2 = EXAMPLE.Column2 
   AND G.Column3 = EXAMPLE.Column3);

SELECT * 
FROM EXAMPLE
```

Basically you have to do a distinct or group by to get all the different groups that you have and use the sequence in a function or you will get the sequence number is not allowed here error from oracle and then do an update.

See complete example on sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf261/8

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. begin transaction
2. Get next sequence in a temp var
3. Disable sequence
4. `update tablename set grp_ID = grp_ID + tmpVar-1`
5. `Select into tempVar max(grp_ID) from tableName`
6. Re-seed sequence based value now in tempvar+1
7. Re-enable sequence
8. commit and end transaction

But i'm confused by something when you add additional records later, they can't simply do sequence.nextval because it's only needed when col1,col2,col3 doesn't already exist, otherwise it should use the group_ID for that unique combination...  just seems odd, doable but odd.

Comment: I just want to replace current value of GRP_ID with database sequence value such that all rows with GRP_ID=1 are assigned sequence.nextval, then all subsequent rows with GRP_ID=2 are assigned sequence.nextval (i.e. next sequence value) and so on. Can this be done through a MERGE SQL (or seomthing else) for faster result? Do not want to use PL/SQL loop over 2 million rows.

Comment: If you must use sequence.nextval, then I know of no way of doing this without a loop.  The above pseudo logic would do that written in a script. It's not a loop but a series of simple statements which achieves the desired result.  There is no loop.  We get the next sequence, lock/remove the sequence so nothing else can use it. update the records, get the max value used, set that as the seed  for the sequence and then re-enable the sequence. (may need to add 1)  I can't recall if sequence starts with teh seed (which I think it does) so then you'd need to add one...